# $\inf (E)$ does not exist and $\sup (E) = (0 , 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\leq$ be the usual order on the field $\Bbb R$ of real numbers. Define an order $\leq$ on $\Bbb R^2$ by $(a,b) \leq (c,d)$ if $(a < c)$, or $(a = c$ and $b \leq d)$. Consider the subset $E$ = {${(\frac{1}{n} , 1 - \frac{1}{n} ) \in \Bbb R^2 : n \in \Bbb N}$}. With respect to $\leq$ which of the following statements is true ?

1. $\inf (E) = (0 ,1)$ and $\sup (E) = (0 , 1)$
2. $\inf (E)$ does not exist and $\sup (E) = (0 , 1)$
3. $\inf (E) = (0 ,1)$ and $\sup (E)$ does not exist
4. Both $\inf (E)$ and $\sup (E)$ do not exist.

We know that  $\inf (E)$ = smallest member or smallest limit point of $E$ and $\sup (E)$ = largest point or largest limit point of $E$.
By using above information, we get
$\inf (E)$ does not exist and $\sup (E) = (0 , 1)$. I think, I'm not on right way. Please help me

Comment: @outofspace0106,Please tell me how to connect the concept discussed between " we see that .......Hence if we had an infimum". with further discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about non-existence of infimum of $E$. I have tried to provide a proof as follows:

We see that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, a \in \mathbb{R}$
$$(0,a)<(\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n})$$
If $\exists (x,y)\in \mathbb{R^{2}}$ such that $$(0,a)<(x,y), \forall a\in \mathbb{R}$$ then $x>0$. Hence, using [Archemedian Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property), $\exists n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n_{0}}<x$.

So we have $$(\frac{1}{n_{0}}, 1-\frac{1}{n_{0}})< (x,y).$$ Hence, if we had an infimum, it must be of the form $(0,a)$ which is not possible because $(0,a)<(0,a+1)$ and $(0,a+1)$ is again a lower bound of $E$.

So we don't have a "greatest" lower bound of $E$.

On the other hand the supremum of $E$ exists and $sup(E)=(1,0)$.

This is because $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $$(\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n})\leq(1,0)$$ and $(1,0)\in E$.

So $(1,0)$ is the "least" upper bound of E.